# Quit the Kernel and start new session automatically

Tags: evaluation, kernel, kernel-startup

**The question** is how to quit the kernel, start a new session automatically, and to be able to run such procedure from e.g. `Button`.

This is especially useful when you can't count on `Dynamic` ([80560](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80560/5478)) or you don't want to care if a given cell is currently visible.

**Motivation**

when developing packages I'm often deleting all output, quitting kernel, loading the package. This can be done in two steps/shortcuts. I want one :)

---

There is closely related/duplicate, but "too old to migrate" question, without final anwer, in SO:

[Quit Kernel in Mathematica...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6152023/4251542)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This can be relatively easily done using extremely useful `$FrontEnd` option `"ClearEvaluationQueueOnKernelQuit"` introduced by [Chris Degnen](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28493/5478).

#### Usage

```
Print @ $SessionID

quitAndEvaluate[
    Print @ $SessionID
]
```

> 25183094379509806957
>
> 25183094575602627552

- `quitAndEvaluate[]` will restart kernel without aby additional tasks. It may be useful if you want to check init.m or Autoload behaviour.
- You can provide procedures delayed in symbol definition (not so obvious since definitions are cleared in a process:

  ```
  ext := (Print[1]; Print[2]);
  quitAndEvaluate[ext]
  ```

#### Code

```
SetAttributes[quitAndEvaluate, HoldAll];

quitAndEvaluate[proc_Symbol] := Unevaluated[quitAndEvaluate[proc]] /. OwnValues[proc];

quitAndEvaluate[after___] := With[{
 currentSetting = CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "ClearEvaluationQueueOnKernelQuit"]
 },
  Composition[
    (SelectionMove[#, All, Notebook]; SelectionEvaluate[#]) &
    ,
    CreateDocument[#, Visible -> False, WindowSize -> {Automatic, 100}] &
    ,
    Cell[#, "Input"] & /@ # &
    ,
    BoxData /@ # &

    ]@{

     MakeBoxes[ CurrentValue[ $FrontEndSession, "ClearEvaluationQueueOnKernelQuit" ] = False; ]
     ,
 MakeBoxes[ Quit[]; ]
     ,
 MakeBoxes[ after; CurrentValue[ $FrontEndSession, 
      "ClearEvaluationQueueOnKernelQuit" ] = currentSetting;
       NotebookClose[EvaluationNotebook[]]; $Line = 0;]
    }
]
```

There is a funny thing with `WindowSize`. Even though the notebook is invisible, you have to set explicitly any dummy value, otherwise it won't work. :)

#### Description

It basicaly creates a new invisible notebook with 3 cells and evaluates it.

The first cell sets our option to `False`.

The second `Quit[]s` the Kernel.

The third restores FrontEnd option. Evaluates your code and deletes that notebook.

Comment: I think there should be a `$Line=0;` after `NotebookClose[EvaluationNotebook[]];`

Comment: @Kuba +1 for the neat solution. I find though, that the responsiveness of `"ClearEvaluationQueueOnKernelQuit"` is not really what one might have hoped for given that eking out a few seconds savings is the main point. One would expect that the time to complete the action of a corresponding button press would be ~QuitTime + LaunchTime but my usage indicates that the actual behaviour is more like ~QuitTime + LaunchTime+5s which kind of makes it not worthwhile.

Comment: Also, don't you want it to be `$FrontEndSession` all the way through? (n.b. the first setting of `currentSetting` uses `$FrontEnd`). Having said this, using `$FrontEnd` all the way through somehow shaves a couple of seconds but at around 10s to start with it is still kind of unwieldy. But a [warning for accidentally setting $FrontEnd persistently](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228484/why-does-it-take-so-long-to-quit),

Comment: @RonaldMonson yes, $FrontEndSession is more appropriate to get the `currentSetting`.  About timings, I will check tomorrow. About responsiveness, I surely agree but that's all I was able to come up with.

Comment: I think this no longer works on Mathematica 12.0. Can someone confirm?

Comment: @JuanC97 it works in 13.3 though it takes a long time to spin a fresh kernel.