# Is there a way to fully restart a Mathematica session from the front end?

Tags: front-end

Sometimes my *Mathematica* environment gets sufficiently fouled up that a full restart is the best way to move forward.

By "full restart" I mean the equivalent of running `File > Quit` followed by re-starting a new *Mathematica* process.

Can this entire cycle be done directly from the front end?

Comment: what about typing `Quit[]` ?

Comment: …or `Exit[]`? $\phantom{}$

Comment: Similar issues have been discussed before, for instance: [(850)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/850/how-do-i-clear-all-user-defined-symbols) and [(82803)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82803/quit-the-kernel-and-start-new-session-automatically).

Comment: Assuming the question is about restarting the frontend rather than the kernel, this works for me on WIndows: `SystemOpen[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "Mathematica"}]];
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["FrontEndQuitNonInteractive"]]`. Other operating systems would need a different launch command.