# Using less memory with ParallelMap when modifying random geometric graphs

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks, parallelization

I am generating a large number of graphs with `RandomGraph[SpatialGraphDistribution[n,r]]`, and parallel mapping a function over them which adds vertices (see the code at the end for the details of `addvert`), and sets edge weights.

```
makegraph[nv_, crange_] := Module[{graph},    
graph = addvert[RandomGraph[SpatialGraphDistribution[nv, crange]], 
     fixdverts, crange];    SetProperty[graph, EdgeWeight -> ed[graph]]    ];
```

I then use

```
n = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[density], Ngraphs];
graphs = ParallelMap[makegraph[#, r0] &, n];
```

This is using 25 Gigabytes of memory when I have `Ngraphs=20,000` and `n=2000`. It appears that Mathematica is storing every graph it builds, and this whole data structure is somehow worth 25G of memory.

I have tried to generate the graphs one by one, but this stops me using `ParallelMap`, which is essential for the speed I need here.

I am surprised that these graphs take up that much memory. Am I doing something wrong? Maybe Mathematica can store these graphs more effectively?

```
ed[rg_] := Module[{ge, el},
   ge = GraphEmbedding[rg];
   el = EdgeList[rg];
   EuclideanDistance @@@ Map[ge[[#]] &, el, {2}]
   ];
addvert[gr_, coord_, range_] := Module[{pts, nl, lv, vv, ee},
  pts = GraphEmbedding[gr];
  vv = VertexList@gr;
  lv = Length@vv;
  nl = lv + # & /@ (Range@Length@coord);
  vv = Join[vv, nl];
  ee = Join[
    Flatten[Thread[# <-> 
         Nearest[Thread[pts -> Range[Length[pts]]], 
          coord[[# - lv]], {Infinity, range}]] & /@ nl], 
    EdgeList@gr];
  Graph[vv, ee, VertexCoordinates -> Join[pts, coord]]
  ]
(*addverts[g_,newverts_,range_]:=Fold[addvert[#,#2,range]&,g,newverts]\
;*)
findT[g_] := Module[{l, lfixd},
   l = Length@VertexList@g;
   lfixd = (Length@fixdverts) - 1;
   GraphDistance[g, l - lfixd, 
      l - #] & /@ (Reverse@Range@(Length@fixdverts - 1) - 1)
   ];
makegraph[nv_, crange_] := Module[{graph},
   graph = 
    addvert[RandomGraph[SpatialGraphDistribution[nv, crange]], 
     fixdverts, crange];
   SetProperty[graph, EdgeWeight -> ed[graph]]
   ];
fixdverts = 
  Developer`ToPackedArray[
   Join[{{.5, .5}}, 
    Table[{.5 + 1/2 Cos[t], .5 + 1/2 Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/16}]], 
   Real];
T = ConstantArray[0, {400, 2}];
For[i = 100, i <= 102, i++,
  Clear[graphs, n];
  r0 = 1/(5 (1 + i/20)); density = 7/(Pi r0^2); Ngraphs = 2000;
  Print["Starting r0 = ", N@r0, ", Euclidean Distance = ", 
   N@(1/2) (1/r0), ", Density = ", N@density, ", ExpDegree = ", 
   N@(density Pi r0^2)];
  Print[MemoryInUse[]];
  n = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[density], Ngraphs];
  graphs = ParallelMap[makegraph[#, r0] &, n];
  Print[Ngraphs, " graphs built!"];
  Print[MemoryInUse[]];
  T[[i, 1]] = N@(1/2) (1/r0);
  T[[i, 2]] = 
   Variance[
    1/r0 DeleteCases[Flatten[ParallelMap[findT, graphs]], Infinity]];
  Print["Variance = ", N@T[[i, 2]]];
  s = OpenAppend["variancedata.txt"];
      Write[s, T[[i, 1]], "", T[[i, 2]]];
      Close[s];
  Print[MemoryInUse[]];
  ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graphs produced *are* that large. One can save a considerable amount of memory and time by avoid `Graph` in the output. (`Graph` computes a stores a bunch of potentially superfluous information when it is created. Moreover, `UndirectedEdge`s lead to unpacking of arrays -- a total misconstruction of `Graph` if you ask me.) In my experiments, this reduced the memory consumption to a sixth of the original value.

Moreover, the routine `addvert` is rather inefficient for it calls `Nearest` with the essentially same input over and over again. Finally, the edge weights can be computed immediately without building a graph, so that we can avoid `SetProperty`.

**Edit**

I finally managed to get rid of `RandomGraph[SpatialGraphDistribution[nv, range]]`. This halves the timings for `makegraph2`. I am not sure though, if my substitute does exactly the same. I also cannot tell what the actual values of the constants `MyValueShouldBe1ButItIs2ForCompatibilityReasons` and `MaybeIShouldHaveTheSameValueAsMyPredecessor` should be...

**Code**

```
getedges = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}},
   Block[{i, j, bag},
    bag = Internal`Bag[Most[{0}]];
    i = Compile`GetElement[list, 1];
    Do[
     j = Compile`GetElement[list, k];
     If[i < j,
      Internal`StuffBag[bag, i];
      Internal`StuffBag[bag, j];
      ],
     {k, 2, Length[list]}];
    Internal`BagPart[bag, All]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

ToPack = Developer`ToPackedArray;
ClearAll[makegraph2]
makegraph2[nv_, range_, coord_] := Module[{
    pts, newvertices, newedges, edges, alledges, allpts, e1, e2,
    MyValueShouldBe1ButItIs2ForCompatibilityReasons = 2.,
    MaybeIShouldHaveTheSameValueAsMyPredecessor = 1.
    },
   pts = Join[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {nv, 2}]];
   edges = Partition[Join @@ getedges[
       Nearest[
        pts -> Automatic,
        pts,
        {Infinity, 
         MyValueShouldBe1ButItIs2ForCompatibilityReasons range}
        ]
       ],
     2];
   newvertices = Range[nv + 1, nv + Length[coord]];
   newedges = With[{nearest = Nearest[
        pts -> Automatic,
        coord,
        {Infinity, MaybeIShouldHaveTheSameValueAsMyPredecessor range}
        ]
      }, Transpose[{ToPack[Join @@ (newvertices (1 + 0 nearest))], 
       ToPack[Join @@ nearest]}]
     ];
   alledges = Join[edges, newedges];
   allpts = Join[pts, coord];
   {e1, e2} = Transpose[alledges];
   {
    Range[nv + Length[coord]],
    alledges,
    VertexCoordinates -> allpts,
    EdgeWeight -> 
     Sqrt[Dot[(allpts[[e1]] - allpts[[e2]])^2, ConstantArray[1., 2]]]
    }
   ];
```

Usage example:

```
r0 = N[1/(5 (1 + 100/20))];
density = 7/(Pi r0^2);
fixdverts = Join[ConstantArray[0.5, {1, 2}], CirclePoints[{.5, .5}, {0.5, 0.}, 16]];
Ngraphs = 2000;
n = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[density], Ngraphs];
graphs = ParallelMap[makegraph2[#, r0, fixdverts] &, n, 
     Method -> "CoarsestGrained"]; // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming

{2.45499, 436102072}
```

You get an actual `Graph`, e.g., with `Graph@@graphs[[1]]`.

Comment: Thank you. You are a lantern in the darkness. I didn't realise how expensive the `Graph` structure was. I think I would also have tried to use a list of edges in the end if all else had failed, and maybe compiled some things, but this is nice and quick.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks also for the warm words. Your next step would be to optimize out the call `RandomGraph` if possible.

Comment: I noticed that there is some minor problem with the `Transpose[{ToPack[Join @@ (newvertices (1 + 0 nearest))], 
    ToPack[Join @@ nearest]}]];`? I get that the first two levels cannot be transposed. Do I need `Developer` loaded, as in Developer`ToPackedArray?

Comment: Fixed. (``ToPack = Developer`ToPackedArray;``)

Comment: Actually that fixed it. I think just replaced `ToPack` with ``Developer`ToPackedArray`` at both points and it works nicely.

Comment: Thank you again.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to remove the call to RandomGraph? I found this to be very fast compared to manual methods. But perhaps if you don't build a graph, you only construct a list of edges, it can be sped up?

Comment: Nah, I don't think so anymore. I tried to replace `RandomGraph` by something that builds on `pts=RandomReal[{0,1},{1000,2}]` and `Nearest[pts -> Automatic, pts, {Infinity, range}]` (similar as in my answer) and what came out was essentially as fast as `RandomGraph` (even a bit slower).

Comment: Of course, I cannot be sure. But I have no further ideas, unfortunately.

Comment: I think this is very fast. The only other thing I could do is find the path length variance without using graph distance (so I don't ever build a graph), but that might be slower as well. Anyway, building the graphs at the end is not too costly.

Comment: Okay, I tried once more. Now `makegraph2` is twice as fast as before.

Comment: I’ll try and work out what is going on with the functionality (concerning the issue you have with the constants).

Comment: The graphs have the correct expected degree when I use the constants above. With constants = 1 and 1, I get the a much lower expected degree than intended by setting `r0`. So I think this code has the correct functionality.

Comment: You can set both constants to 1, but you need really to have the parameter of the Poisson variable n set to `4*density`, as the volume of your box is 4, not 1. By setting the constant to 2, and leaving the parameter at `density`, the two effects cancel.

Comment: I am modifying the code to work on the k-NearestNeighbour graph, rather than this unit disk graph. I tried modifying the nearest function to give the k nearest elements, but it doesn't give the k-nearest neighbour graph, as some of the nodes have degree < k. I think something also needs to be modified in the `getedges' function? But I'm not sure I understand some of the code in that function. Is it a simple fix?

Comment: Being k-th nearest neighbour is a nonsymmetric relation, so literally interpreted, the result will be a _directed_ graph. `getedges` is written to produce an undirected graph.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `edges = Partition[
  Join @@ getdirectededges2[
    Nearest[pts -> Automatic, pts, {k, Infinity}]], 2]` in conjunction with `getdirectededges = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}},
  Block[{i},
   i = Compile`GetElement[list, 1];
   Table[
    {i, Compile`GetElement[list, k]},
    {k, 2, Length[list]}]
   ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
  Parallelization -> True,
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ]`.  These edges have to be handed over to `Graph` as `DirectedEdge`s.

Comment: Thank you, this is in fact how I have modified it. It took removing the if condition in the getedges function, and removing the double edges after the graph is built. Or leaving the double edges, as it happens to not matter for my application. But the above is very helpful!