# Automate quitting and restarting Kernel while doing Evaluate Notebook

Tags: kernel

I have multiple notebooks open, with similar variable declaration (am studying test cases), and I want all notebooks to be independent of each other, and also forget it's own evaluation after finishing. I have added

`ClearAll["Global*"]`

at the top of the notebook. Also done: `Default Kernel` as `Local`. Plus assigned `Notebook's Default Context` as `Unique to this Notebook`

But it still retains values.

I just tried adding `Quit` at the end of the notebook, but each time I Evaluate Notebook again (after it has done `Quit` once), my program crashes. I put `Quit` at the beginning of the notebook and did `Evaluate Notebook` but it compiled the first cell with `Quit` and then it stops there.

I am out of ideas, any suggestions?

I need this to be default - never having dependence of notebooks on each other and never remember values after ending one evaluation... I want it automated (right now, I have to do Evaluation > Quit Kernel after each evaluation...

Comment: Since you've asked different contexts to be assigned to each notebook, their variables are no longer in the ```Global` ``` context, so `ClearAll["Global`*"]` is doing nothing. Try `ClearAll[StringJoin[Context[], "*"]]` instead.

Comment: I got error "`ClearAll:: Context[]<>* is not a symbol or a string.`" with `ClearAll[StringJoin[Context[], "*"]]` but I tried with `ClearAll[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]]` and it works perfectly; thank you very much!

Comment: Great! I've summarized my comment and your modification in an answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82803/quit-the-kernel-and-start-new-session-automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've asked for different contexts to be assigned to each notebook, their variables are no longer in the `` Global` ``  context, so `ClearAll["Global*"]` is doing nothing for you. You can extract the name of the current context with `Context[]`, then use `ClearAll[Evaluate@ StringJoin[Context[], "*"]]` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than try to clear all defined variables I like to just quit the kernel to get a clean slate.

To accomplish your goal I would place a single cell at the top of each notebook with the expression

```
Quit[]
```

and then just `Cmd-A` to select all cells and then evaluate them.  First the kernel will quit and then all the other cells will evaluate.  If you find that when it hits the `Quit[]` it no longer evaluates the other cells, then evaluate the following

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "ClearEvaluationQueueOnKernelQuit"] = False
```

I have no idea why that isn't the default value for that option.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! One idea why it's the default: You want the kernel to stop, as in stop now, give me back control cuz I made a mistake. Another reason: the rest of the queue often depends on initialization, without which its execution fills the notebook with error messages. -- Alternatively they could have had two kinds of quit, like the C and AC buttons on old calculators.

Comment: That makes sense - I always considered the menu item Evaluate->Quit Kernel to be the "stop, stop now" command because it does it even when the kernel is hanging.  I probably found `ClearEvaluationQueueOnKernelQuit` as an option shortly after I started using Mathematica so it seems natural to me.

Comment: Yeah, it's unlikely a user selects a sequence of cells in the middle of which is `Quit[]` and the following cells require initialization. That's their fault. And you can't abort by typing `Quit[]` in the middle of an evaluating queue. -- BTW, do you know what happens if `ClearEvaluationQueueOnKernelQuit` is false and you kill the kernel externally? Does evaluation restart? I guess you can always kill the FE if you do something stupid, but you lose unsaved work.

Comment: The Evaluation->Quit Kernel is a nuclear option, will not restart any computations after that